# React redux saga - using race has no effect at all

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I have the following saga effect:

```
function* loginSaga() {
  const logoutTimeoutCreationDate: string | null = yield localStorage.getItem('logoutTimeoutCreationDate');

  let logoutTimeout: number;

  if (!logoutTimeoutCreationDate || +logoutTimeoutCreationDate + 5000 < new Date().getTime()) {
    yield localStorage.setItem('logoutTimeoutCreationDate', new Date().getTime().toString());

    logoutTimeout = yield 5000;
  } else {
    logoutTimeout = yield +logoutTimeoutCreationDate + 5000 - new Date().getTime();
  }
  
  yield race([
    function*() {
      yield delay(logoutTimeout);
      yield put(authActions.logout());
    },
    function*() {
      yield take(authActions.AUTH_LOGOUT);
    },
  ]);
}
```

All the code before `yield race(..)` works as expected, but the `yield race(..)` has no effect. Meaning like it does not even exist. I insert `console.log()`s line to check it (inside the `function*() {...}`) in both - but nothing got consoled.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use other syntax without yield:

```
  const [delayAction]: [CallEffect, TakeEffect] = yield race<CallEffect | TakeEffect>([
    delay(logoutTimeout),
    take(authActions.AUTH_LOGOUT)
  ]);

  if(delayAction){
    yield put(authActions.logout());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `race` wrong way. You can fix like this:

```
  const [delayAction, logoutAction] = yield race([
    yield delay(logoutTimeout),
    yield take(authActions.AUTH_LOGOUT)
  ]);

  if(delayAction){
    yield put(authActions.logout());
  }
```